# std::set_intersection with custom comparator

Tags: c++, set-intersection

I'm trying to understand the syntax for `std::set_intersection` when using a custom comparator.
I'm trying to get the intersection of sets `one` and `two`, which should result in a set (`intersect`) containing only element `f2`.

I get error:

> passing ‘const Foo’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    std::string str;
};

struct Compare_custom
{
    bool operator () (const Foo & lhs, const Foo & rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.str.size() > rhs.str.size());
    }
};

int main ()
{
    std::set<Foo, Compare_custom> one, two, intersect;

    Foo f1, f2, f3;

    f1.str = "-";
    f2.str = "--";
    f3.str = "---";

    one.insert(f1);
    one.insert(f2);

    two.insert(f2);
    two.insert(f3);

    std::set_intersection(one.begin(), one.end(),
        two.begin(), two.end(),
        intersect.begin(), Compare_custom());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `std::set_intersection` wrongly for `std::set`. Try this :

```
std::set_intersection(one.begin(), one.end(),
        two.begin(), two.end(),
        std::inserter(intersect, intersect.begin()), Compare_custom());
```

Comment: It’s actually fairly difficult (not impossible, but harder than you might expect) to use a lambda as the comparator for a `std::set`, and those need to be sorted using the same function as `std::set_intersection` uses.

Comment: @DanielH I'm not sure what you mean, can you explain? Or feel free to update answer if it's not accurate. BTW I tested implementation using lambda and I think it will do what OP expect.

Comment: set_intersection with a custom compare will only work if the two sets involved use the same compare function!

Comment: @rubenvb  I see, now I get what DanielH said, Thanks.

Comment: @rubenvb That’s part of what I was saying, but I also meant it would be difficult to use the lambda as the `set`’s comparator. You need to specify the *type* of the lambda as a template parameter, and they won’t have default constructors until C++2a. The amount of boilerplate in using a lambda is enough that it’s probably easier to write the comparator struct directly, as in the question.

Comment: @Hamed See https://youtu.be/dvLKY-oWqn0 for an exploration of the difficulties involved in using lambdas as `std::set` comparators. The solution that would work best here is at around 4:33, and it doesn't have much benefit over just declaring the struct.

Comment: @DanielH Nice, Thank you.